# Get Datasource Item from Rendering with Powershell

Tags: sxa, powershell-extensions

I am looking for powershell script to get *datasource item* of a rendering. Right now I am getting path of datasource item. But since I am using SXA, I expect few paths like,  *local:/Data/Hero Banner*
Also I could not find any relevant property of RenderingItem object that could suffice my need. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
$itemRenderings = Get-Rendering -Item $item -Device $defaultLayout -FinalLayout

    foreach ( $renderingItem in $itemRenderings ){
        $renderingItem.Datasource
}
```

Comment: Not really. It gives path and as I mentioned, its not always a path in case of SXA. So I am looking for generic logic to get datasource item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this for handling paths like, local:/Data/Hero Banner

```
$itemRenderings = Get-Rendering -Item $item -Device $defaultLayout -FinalLayout

foreach ($renderingItem in $itemRenderings) {
    $dataSourcePath = $renderingItem.Datasource

    # Check if the data source path has a special prefix
    if ($dataSourcePath.StartsWith("local:")) {
        # Handle "local:" prefix
        $dataSourceItemPath = $dataSourcePath.Replace("local:", "$item.Paths.Path")
        $dataSourceItem = Get-Item -Path $dataSourceItemPath
    }
    else {
        # Default handling without any prefixes
        $dataSourceItemPath = $dataSourcePath
        $dataSourceItem = Get-Item -Path $dataSourceItemPath
    }

    # Output the data source item
    $dataSourceItem
}
```